# "Add Answer" button spawns new answer form instead of submitting previewed answer

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, answers, ios-app

When I "Preview" an answer I've written within the iOS app to a question, I am presented with the following screen:

[image: Preview Answer Screen]

Satisfied with my response, I tapped the "Add An Answer" button expecting my previewed answer to be submitted. Instead I got a new answer field. Fortunately I was able to cancel out of that form, taking me back to the above screen. Looking at it a second time, then I noticed the "Submit" link button in the top right corner.

So this is partly a bug report and partly a request.

Instead of removing the button, consider...

- Keeping the button there, but when I tap on it submit my answer
- Changing the button wording to "Add Answer", "Add My Answer" or "Add This Answer" -- Something to help me know that the button has changed it's behavior based on the new context.
- Removing the top "Submit" button. It makes sense in the previous screen where I'm writing a response and half my screen is taken with the keyboard. But in this mode, the keyboard is no longer up and my focus is on the response I just wrote. My eyes will end at the end of my response.

Comment: I think just remove

Comment: "add comment" needs removing too. generates an error if you try

Comment: And if you tap the `...` on the right next to Answered, and select `Edit`, the app crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in 0.1.19.  Arie fixed it.  Not sure why he didn't post about it.  Hates rep I guess.

Comment: The "answered" bar is still there in 0.1.19. 
Generates errors if you tap the `...` and press Edit. Should that be a new bug report, or just fixed as part of this one